# AngularFire2 firestore take(1) on doc valueChanges

Tags: angular, firebase, angularfire, google-cloud-firestore

Using AngularFire2 I try to get data from a single Firestore document. **What works is**:

```
this.addressRef = afs.doc<Address>('addresses/key')
this.addressRef.valueChanges().subscribe(val => {......}
```

I want to run the subscription code just once. Normally I use take(1) to achieve this (works with the Firebase DB). **But this code**:

```
this.addressRef.valueChanges().take(1).subscribe(val => {......}
```

**gives error**: TypeError: this.addressRef.valueChanges(...).take is not a function.

VS Code is listing the take action. Is this a bug in AngularFire2, am I doing this wrong or is there an other (better) way to stop the subscription after the data is fetched? I also tried topromise but this also failed.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

**update**

Because this answer has received a lot of attention, I have provided an updated answer. You should, in general, try to think reactively when programming with observables. There are some great tutorials, but [this one is](https://blog.strongbrew.io/thinking-reactively-in-angular-and-rxjs/) good.

**New solution**

```js
user$ = this.afDs.doc<User>('users/NaGjauNy3vYOzp759xsc')
  .valueChanges().pipe(
    take(1) // Here you can limit to only emit once, using the take operator
  )
```

And in your template, you subscribe to your observable.

```html
{{(user$ | async).name}}
```

**Context**

This way of solving the problem has multiple benefits:

- If you wan't to transform data, you just throw in a map operator
- You can filter events with the rxjs filter operator
- Create other streams, based on the user$ stream
- easy debugging, because other developers can see the flow of data in your app in a more transparent way

For example (creating another stream, that only emits if the user is admin, and creates a new title):

```js
adminTitle$ = this.user$.pipe(
  filter(user => user.title === 'admin'),
  map(user => `${user.name} (admin)`)
)
```

**Old answer**

You can achieve this by doing the following:

```js
this.userDoc = afDs.doc<User>('users/NaGjauNy3vYOzp759xsc');
this.userDoc.valueChanges()
  .pipe(take(1))
  .subscribe(v => {
    this.user = v;
  });
```

Comment: Okay, at first I did not see much new in your answer as I already use the same code but take() doesn't work in my setup. But after studying your stackblitz I found that my imports are different. I guess they were auto generated by VC. I had "rxjs/operator/take" as import path. Changed it to "rxjs/add/operator/take" as in your example and now the take() works. So thank you for providing the complete code. I will do further research about these different paths.

Comment: and now everytime you need for example user.uid to write other code, you need to do this inside the subscribe? this makes the code look so weird and nested. Can't you get the current user uid from the database and do something with it in your component (so not html) without a subscribe?

Comment: @Ruben do you still need help with this? The short answer is that yes - you have to subscribe. But you don't need to call it more than once :)

Comment: @DauleDK thanks, I get it but my code is just looking weird, I need the currently logged in user UID on almost every page in my app, but I need to subscribe (once) every time, it would be easier if the UID was a global var I could access everywhere without using subscribe. Most of my other code should run after I get the UID so it's kinda annoying

Comment: Hi @Ruben - to avoid this you have 2 options if you ask me. You could either store the UID in the browsers storage. In Angular you can simply do `localStorage.setItem('uid', <uid>)` and then when you need it `localStorage.getItem(uid)`. You could also make a service, injected to your app module. Just remember to clear the uid, when the user logs out :)

Comment: With rxjs version 6.5.4, I could use take only by `import { take } from 'rxjs/operators';`