# How to query for a single doc with AngularFirestore?

Tags: angular, typescript, firebase, angularfire2, angularfire

How can I build an Observable that's limited to a single doc?

This builds an Observable when querying for any number of docs:

**foo.component.ts**

```
import { AngularFirestore } from '@angular/fire/firestore';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';

...

export class FooComponent implements OnInit {

...

    docs: Observable<any[]>;

    constructor(private db: AngularFirestore) {
        this.docs = db.collection('myCollection', ref => ref.where('name', '==', 'foobar')).valueChanges();

}
```

**foo.component.html**

```
<div *ngFor="let doc of docs | async">
    {{ doc.name }}, {{ doc.address }}
</div>
```

How can I do this when I know there's only 1 doc that'll be returned? I just won't know the doc ID in advance.

Something like the code above, except with just `doc: Observable<any>;` instead of `docs: Observable<any[]>;` so I don't have to use an `*ngFor` loop over the results?

I've tried

```
this.doc = db.collection('myCollection', ref => ref.where('name', '==', 'foobar').limit(1)).valueChanges();
```

Comment: added "import { take } from 'rxjs/operators';" but it doesn't give the 1 doc from the query :(

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46654670/angularfire2-firestore-take1-on-doc-valuechanges/46665581 see this for reference. and you have to import `import { take } from 'rxjs/operators';`

Comment: what are you getting ?

Comment: the object "docs: Observable<any[]>" works fine, but "doc: Observable<any>" doesn't have any value .. not even an error

Comment: what if you add `.subscribe(res => console.log('response', res));` what do you get logged ?

Comment: im seeing it in response [{...}]. it's in [0] ... but I'm unable to access it in the html file with "{{ doc.name }}" or "{{ doc[0].name }}" ... in *.ts, "console.log(res[0].name)" works though

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/firestore-forms have a look at this stackblitz link and see last "Firestore DB Persistent"

Comment: hi Gaurang, that shows a document given a known doc id. I'm trying to query for a document without knowing which doc id to target

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Working stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-v7yff2

Based on https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-lymeyp, you just need to do the following in the component

```
crazinessToObserveASingleDoc() {
        this.singleDoc = this.db.collection('users', ref => ref.where('email', '==', this.email)).valueChanges().pipe(
          tap(docs => console.log('docs', docs)),
          map(val => val.length > 0 ? val[0] : null)
        )
    }
```

and in the template

```
<div>
    <span class="title">Document with email <span class="italics">{{ email }}</span>:</span>
    <div *ngIf="singleDoc | async as doc">{{ doc.name }}, {{ doc.email }}</div>
</div>
```

**Previous solution**

Don't do `take(1)` as suggested in some comments: it completes the observable and then you will stop listening for changes (why using a realtime database then?). Also, you will still receive an array of results...

If you don't know the id of the document, what you need to do is this:

```
const doc: Observable<any | null> = 
   db.collection('myCollection', ref => ref.where('name', '==', 'foobar'))
     .valueChanges()
     .pipe(map(val => val.length > 0 : val[0] : null));
```

where map if from `rxjs/operators`.

Comment: when I do this, "{{ doc.name }}" remains empty, and "{{ (doc | async)?.name }}" gives the error "Error: InvalidPipeArgument: '[object Object]' for pipe 'AsyncPipe'". But when I put both examples in the *.html file, "{{ doc.name }}" and "{{ (doc | async)?.name }}", "{{ doc.name }}" populates with the expected value. Ideas?

Comment: can you reproduce on stackblitz? Using "{{ (doc | async)?.name }}" should be the way to go because of the observable returned by firebase. You can debug by using "{{doc | async | json}}" (or just "{{doc | json}}" if you say that works for you) and by adding a console.log(val) inside the map I posted

Comment: here's my StackBlitz, thanks for the idea of putting it up there. https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-lymeyp

Comment: got it! I had an issue forking but I made it work, I updated my answer with the relevant code (and I realized I make an error in the if in my previous response )

Comment: thanks @michelepatrassi :) could you link me to your fork? (I'm new to using StackBlitz and I don't see how to see forked projects).. when I add that code to mine, I'm not getting any results

Comment: I think you miss the tap import. here's the working stackblitz  https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-v7yff2